# how to use date and time interval using time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql

```
sample time = '07:00:00'
Select date_add(sampletime, interval '24' HOUR), interval '20' minute) as samplefrom sample.time;
```

How could I use combination of hour and mins interval?

or

```
sample datetime = '2014/01/01 07:00:00'
```

SQL Query for date hour mins computation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too complicated.

```
SELECT '2014-01-01 07:00:00' + INTERVAL 24 HOUR + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE;
```

or

```
SELECT '2014-01-01 07:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE;
```

If you insist on using the `date_add()` function, you forgot to use it twice.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2014-01-01 07:00:00', INTERVAL 24 HOUR), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE);
```